# How to implement perturbation theory without unperturbed Hamiltonian?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, perturbation-theory, variational-calculus

In perturbation theorem, the system Hamiltonian is $H=H_0+H'$, the eigenproblem of $H_0$ is already solved, and $H'$ is a little perturbation compare to $H_0$, then the eigenproblem of $H$ can be solved perturbatively.

But if I have a set of state $\{|\phi\rangle\}$ that is very close to the eigenstate of $H$, but don't know the unperturbed Hamiltonian $H_0$, if I can still use the perturbation theory? And more, if I only know a state $|\phi_0\rangle$ that is very close to the ground state of $H$, can I use perturbation theory to approach the ground state of $H$?

Actually the question is originate from, when I implemented variational step to get a approximation of the ground state of $H$, can I use perturbation theory to further improve the accuracy?

Comment: There *is* no $H_0$ in your problem, only $H$, for which you have an approximate ground state. Projecting it out of your calculation might, in principle, net you further approximate eigenstates.

Answer (score 1):

**Answering the first question**

Yes. If the set of states forms a complete basis for Hilbert space. You calculate all the matrix elements of Hamiltonian and then take the diagonal part as the unperturbed Hamiltonian $H_0$ and the non diagonal parts as the perturbation part. Now you can use time independent perturbation theory.

Comment: Thank you! And what is the case if I only know one state that is close to the ground state of total Hamiltonian H?

Comment: Even if you had the exact groundstate of $H$, in general you would need to solve the eigenvalue problem for the rest of the Hamiltonian (excluding the groundstate subspace).